# How did a candidate nominate themselves after the deadline?

Tags: bug, status-deferred, election

User [Way to infinity](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/53489/way-to-infinity) nominated themselves at 20:11:59 UTC:

[image]

And yet the nomination period ended 20:00:00 UTC:

[image]

This isn't really normal, I believe. If I had to guess, the user opened the nomination page before the deadline, and submitted after. Is that really the expected behavior?

Comment: Also worth investigating: did they manage to sneak into the top 20 despite having a too low rep count to qualify?

Comment: @DanielR Just enough, the previously twentieth-ranked candidate had 724 or 729.

Comment: I was going to make a job that I was gonna nominate myself, but the nomination ended; now I'm glad that I didn't make that joke! :-)

Comment: @DanielFischer Right, thanks! I just realized I could have done that dirty work myself...

Comment: @geoff Why is this status-bydesign, when Shog9 says below that it's a bug, and thought the correct action was to de-nominate the candidate? Is it a bug or isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to defer that until the next election @MJD

Comment: Meant to defer what,  exactly?

Comment: @MJD: It just means that they'll look closer at it some point in the future (the next election, it seems).

Comment: @GeoffDalgas: Defer until the next math.SE election, or the next election _somewhere_ on the SE network?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apparently there's a grace period on the nomination cut-off. I'm also inclined to consider that a bug, albeit one we haven't really had to worry about much.

For the time being, I've left the nominee a polite "better luck next time" and removed him from the running, as strictly-speaking he should not have been allowed to submit a nomination.

The primary election will continue with the top 20 nominees (by reputation) out of a total of 23.